# differential map of a map $\phi$ as an element of $T^*M \otimes \phi^{-1}TN$

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $f : M \to N$ be map between Riemannian manifolds.Let $(x^1,\cdots, x^m)$ and $(f^1, \cdots, f^n)$ be local coordinates at $p \in M$ and $f(p) \in N$ respectively. Then in ch- 8 of the book " Riemannian geometry and Geometric anlaysis" by Jurgen jost, it is written that we consider the differential of $f$ as $$df = \frac{\partial f^i}{\partial x^{\alpha}} dx^{\alpha} \otimes \frac{\partial}{\partial f^i},$$ which is an element of $T^*M \otimes f^{-1}TN$. It has been written to study about harmonic maps but I am not getting that how can we write it like this.Can someone explain it? Thanks!

Comment: Why $\phi^{-1}TN$? You should be able to think of $d\phi$ as a $TN$-valued one-form, i.e., it takes a vector field on $M$ to a vector field on $N$ via $d\phi$. That would make it a section of $T^*M\otimes TN$.

Comment: @Neal: The bundles $T^*M$ and $TN$ in your tensor product don't have the same base space. :)

Comment: @user103005: Could you please clarify what you're uncertain about? (Particularly, are you not sure where your displayed expression $X$ comes from, about the vector bundle of which $X$ is a section, or something else?)

Comment: @user86418 Touche :)

Comment: This is written usually as  $T^*M \otimes f^{*}(TN)$ or ${\text Hom}(TM,f^{*}(TN))$ (you must have replaced $f$ by $\phi$ by mistake), where $f^{*}TN$ is the pull-back of $TN$ by $f$. See for example the beginning of Milnor and Stashef book for the definition.

Comment: @user86418: I am not getting the  expression which i have written above.Please give its explanation , if possible. Thanks! I am not even able to think how can we write a differential map as a section of $T^*M \otimes f^{-1} TN$ as i know that the differential map is a mapping from $TM$ to $TN$.

Answer (score 1):

If $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional vector spaces, there is a natural isomorphism $\operatorname{Hom}(V, W) \simeq V^* \otimes W$: If $v^{*} \in V^{*}$ and $w \in W$, then $v^{*} \otimes w$ corresponds to the linear transformation $T:V \to W$ defined by $T(x) = v^{*}(x)\cdot w$.

If $V$ and $W$ are equipped with ordered bases $B = \{v_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha=1}^{n}$ and $B' = \{w_{i}\}_{i=1}^{m}$, respectively, and if $\{v^{\alpha}\}$ denotes the basis of $V^{*}$ dual to $B$, then a transformation $T$ with coordinate matrix $[T]_{B'}^{B} = [a_{\alpha}^{i}]$ corresponds to
$$
\sum_{\alpha=1}^{n} \sum_{i=1}^{m} a_{\alpha}^{i} v^{\alpha} \otimes w_{i}.
$$

Here, you have a local frame $\{\partial/\partial x^{\alpha}\}$ on $M$, the dual coframe $\{dx^{\alpha}\}$, and a local frame $\{\partial/\partial f^{i}\}$ for the pullback $f^{-1}(TN)$ of the tangent bundle of $N$.

The differential $df$ may be viewed either as a bundle map from $TM$ to $f^{-1}(TN)$ (the latter viewed naturally as "the restriction of $TN$ to the image of $f$") or, via the natural isomorphism above taken fibrewise, as a section of $T^{*}M \otimes f^{-1}(TN)$.

The partial derivatives of the components of $f$ with respect to the coordinates $x^{\alpha}$ are, by definition, the components of $df$, so that
$$
df = \sum_{\alpha=1}^{n} \sum_{i=1}^{m} \frac{\partial f^{i}}{\partial x^{\alpha}} dx^{\alpha} \otimes \frac{\partial}{\partial f^{i}}.
$$

Comment: Thanks! I fully understood now by your explanation.You have explained nicely.